# Нет перевода в FAQ сайта в разделе "Очереди проверок"

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

## Проблема

Нет перевода в FAQ сайта в разделе "Очереди проверок".
Как видите здесь есть ссылки на другие страницы на английском.

Так вот, в данном случае не переведены ни ссылки, ни даже сами страницы. Можете проверить: [How do I use the Reopen votes queue?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-reopen)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Предложения

Непереведенные ссылки предлагаю перевести следующим образом:

- Что такое очередь проверок "Голоса за переоткрытие"?
- Что такое очередь проверок "Голоса за закрытие"?
- Почему я был временно отстранен от голосования?
- [Есть перевод]
- [Есть перевод]
- Как использовать очередь проверок "Первые сообщения"?
- Как использовать очередь проверок "Предлагаемые правки"?
- Как использовать очередь проверок "Запоздалые ответы"?

Считаю необходимым перевод на русский. Ну, предлагать перевод тех страниц полностью, я, пожалуй, не буду.

P.S. Перевод не дословный. Названия очередей проверок взяты из [списка очередей проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: @Danis Да, это именно оно. Я его почему-то не нашел. Свой вопрос, пожалуй, закрою, буду там переводить.:)